# How do I update information in the database using DatabaseLibrary library?

Tags: robotframework

I need to change the email for some records in the database.

Using the DatabaseLibrary library, I made the following code:

```
*** Settings ***

Library     DatabaseLibrary

*** Variables ***
${DB_NAME}             xxxxxxxx 
${DB_USER_NAME}        xxxxxxxx 
${DB_USER_PASSWORD}    xxxxxxxx 
${DB_HOST}             xxxxxxxx 
${DB_PORT}             xxxxxxxx 

*** Test Cases ***
Update Email    
    Connect To Database    psycopg2         ${DB_NAME}
    ...                    ${DB_USER_NAME}
    ...                    ${DB_USER_PASSWORD}
    ...                    ${DB_HOST}
    ...                    ${DB_PORT}
    Execute Sql String     update user_contact set contact = 'email123@email.com' where contact = '123456@email.com'
```

The test runs successfully, but when validating the change in the database, there was no change in the email, remaining the same as the one registered.

[Test Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Rf3o.png)

Am I doing it right?
Is there another way to do this?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I see the console output you posted, but does the log.html show you the output result of Execute Sql String ?
Have you tried capturing the result of running that keyword?
${result} =    Execute Sql String     update user....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script looks correct, but maybe you should `Disconnect From Database` in the end.

There is this option: `Set optional input sansTran to True to run command without an explicit transaction commit or rollback.`
It should not be the cause for the issue, because the default is to commit. However you may try to explicitly do a commit after it:

```
Execute Sql String     Commit
```